# What is the best floor pump?

Tags: product-rec, pump

I'm looking for a pump at home to use with my high pressure (100-120 psi) road bike tires.  My bike has presta valves, but I would like to be able to use it on Schrader valves, should I get a bike with them.

Who has a floor pump that they like?

Comment: You're probably going to pick up a [subjective] tag, you may want to rephrase to remove the subjective nature of the question.

Comment: as far as a brand goes this is totally subjective.

Comment: Perhaps adding criteria such as durability, ease of use, et cetera would narrow the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have [a Specialized pump](http://www.specialized.com/us/en/bc/SBCEqProduct.jsp?spid=47578&menuItemId=9306&eid=5134) which works very well for both high-volume and high pressure tires.

I've also used a couple of different [Joe Blow](http://www.topeak.com/products/Floor-Pumps) pumps from [Topeak](http://www.topeak.com/), which worked pretty well.

In light of this, I'm of the opinion that your best bet is to hit up your LBS and see what they have, and what you like using.  For me, handle shape and size plays a big part (you need comfort to pump up a 26"x4" tire).  Plenty of pumps work for both types of valve, and your LBS should be able to point out which pumps can do this.  Some require you to screw off a cap and flip something over, others can have a two-sided head, and others (like my Specialized) have a head that works for both without any changes.

Comment: I've got a Topeak Joe Blow that I've had for quite sometime. It's proven to be MUCH sturdier than any other pumps I've had.  Not only do I use it to pump up all my bike tires, but I also use it for my car tires (I have multiple sets of various types that require frequent pressure changes for racing).

Comment: Another thing to look for: how easy it is to read the gauge.  Some have a gauge at floor level, others put it at the top, some have easier to read designs, etc...  Mine has a little triangle you can spin into a spot, so that you can just pump until the needle matches up with the triangle.

Comment: Topeak Joe Blow here too.  Nice gauge, strong, big volume of air/pump, each stroke gives me about 5 psi.  Tires almost always back off to 100 overnight, 4 strokes per tire = 120 psi; going riding!

Comment: @freiheit which pump is this? That sounds fantastic!

Comment: @Jack M. Your link to specialized is no longer good. I usually specify in body link info not contained in the link itself (i.e. model, if the link is just 'id=e125…' etc.

Answer (score 3):

I have a 15+ year old Silca floor pump with a gauge and Presta attachment plus a screw-on Schrader adapter. I replaced a gasket about 4 years ago. I ride a lot so it gets frequent use.

That being said, if I were in the market for a new floor pump, I would get one made of quality materials and one that has replaceable parts.

The old Silca will probably be in my will at this rate...

Comment: +1 for Silca. Inexpensive in the first place and everything's user-replaceable and easily available. Worn washer? Buy a new one for £1 and your pump is as good as new.

Answer (score 3):

The question is marginal 'cos its asking about specifics which change over time and products which are not necessarily universally available.

My (very wonderful) trackpump has certain attributes that make me like it but given that its at least 6, more likely 8 or 10 years old so... better to define the things that make me like it:

1. It works i.e. it puts a lot of air in the tyres efficiently (hard to evaluate but it is key).
2. Big, clear, gauge - at the top - with a "target" marker so your getting the right pressures
3. Smarthead - don't have to worry about presta or schraeder just push it on and lift the lever
4. Very stable in use - big base to put one's foot etc.
5. Solid. Very solid.
6. If you put everything away properly the hose loops through a hook, there's a hole to park the head and there a "hook" so that you can carry it by the handle.
7. Last but not least, its still working a lot of years.

The keys are 2, 3 and 4 the rest are bonus features that differentiate it from the alternatives.

For what its worth, its a Topeak Jo Blow Pro - but what resemblence mine bears to a current model is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Tioga, which has a universal connector so that you can put onto either Schrader or presta valves.  The current model (Zero  Comp Floor Pump) looks pretty much like what I have.  It also has a pressure gauge.  Very versatile and does more than enough for me.